# Categories and Sub Categories in custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I find and use the following code to display sub categories for default taxonomy 'category' on my site, but I created a custom taxonomy , and can not alter the code so that he was doing the same thing for the new taxonomy, help please

```
 <?php

if(is_category()) {
    $subcategories = get_terms('category', 'parent='.get_query_var('cat'));

    if(empty($subcategories)) {
        $thiscat = get_term(get_query_var('cat'),'category');
        $subcategories = get_terms('category', 'parent='.$thiscat->parent.'');
    }
    if(empty($subcategories)) $subcategories = array();
    if(!empty($subcategories)) {
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
            if(get_query_var('cat') == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
            echo '
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$subcat->term_id.$current.'">
                <a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="'.$subcat->description.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a>
            </li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
else {
    // If no current cat query, just get the top level ones using wp_list_categories.
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&depth=1');?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This is very vague. You need to explain how you're trying to alter the code, and what you're trying to get it to do. Please show what alterations you've tried and explain what wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, the code works as I wanted, but if it can be optimize I'll be glad to help ... This code displays the subcategories to the main categories of taxonomies.
If anyone should use, just change 'auto' to the name of your taxonomy. my custom taxonomy is 'auto'

```
    <?php

if(is_tax()) {
    $subcategories = get_terms('auto', 'parent='.get_queried_object()->term_id);

    if(empty($subcategories)) {
        $thiscat = get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id,'auto');
        $subcategories = get_terms('auto', 'parent='.$thiscat->parent.'');
    }
    if(empty($subcategories)) $subcategories = array();
    if(!empty($subcategories)) {
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
            if(get_queried_object()->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
            echo '
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$subcat->term_id.$current.'">
                <a href="'.get_term_link($subcat,'auto').'" title="'.$subcat->description.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a>
            </li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
else {
    // If no current cat query, just get the top level ones using wp_list_categories.
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=auto&title_li=&depth=1');?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  for the corrected code.
I have added a bit for people who want to exit of the loop once they come to any end. Instead of showing the parent categories tree i modified a bit to display the image and title of the of the products or services under that specific category. Following is the code

```
if(is_tax()) {
    $subcategories = get_terms('product_categories', 'parent='.get_queried_object()->term_id);
  // this is the change which display all the products in the specific category if it does not have child categories
    if(empty($subcategories)) {
        $thiscat = get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id,'product_categories');
    if (have_posts('thiscat')):while (have_posts('thiscat')) : the_post('thiscat');{?>
        <div class="box cat-item-<?php $subcat->name.$current ;?>" style="min-height: 231px; margin-bottom:10px">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php $post->name ;?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?></a>
        <h5><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5></h5></div>
                    <?php } 

                    endwhile;   
                    else : {

                                ?>
        <div class="box  cat-item cat-item-<?php $subcat->name.$current; ?>" style="min-height: 231px; margin-bottom:10px">
        <h5>Products will be upadated later. Do visit Later </h5 >          
        </div>
                                        <?php }


                endif;
}
if(empty($subcategories)) $subcategories = array();
if(!empty($subcategories)) {
    echo '<div class="fixed-row clearfix dynamic-fixedRow-735" id="row_order_2">';

    foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
        if(get_queried_object()->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
        echo '
        <div class="box cat-item cat-item-'.$subcat->name.$current.'" style="min-height: 231px; margin-bottom:10px"><h5>
            <a href="'.get_term_link($subcat,'product_categories').'" title="'.$subcat->description.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a>
        </h5></div>';

    }
```